# How do I evaluate the limit $\lim _{ x\to -\infty } \frac { 2x-3 }{ \sqrt { x^{ 2 }+7x-2 } } $ with a radical?

Tags: calculus, limits

I'm trying to evaluate

> $$\lim _{ x\to -\infty  } \frac { 2x-3 }{ \sqrt { x^{ 2 }+7x-2 }  } $$

by rationalizing the denominator, but I am not getting anywhere. Can someone please help me with this?

Thanks

Comment: Check again your function.

Comment: Should the limit be as $x \to \infty$? This function is continuous at $x=0$ so as it is written you can just plug in $0$ and get the answer.

Comment: @Salahamam_Fatima Oh sorry, I mean't $x \to -\infty$. The problem has been revised.

Comment: what is the question? $x \to \infty$ or $x \to -\infty$?

Comment: @SiongThyeGoh The question is as x approaches negative infinity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{2x-3}{\sqrt{x^2+7x-2}}
&= \lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x(2-\dfrac3x)}{\sqrt{x^2(1+\dfrac7x-\dfrac{2}{x^2})}} \\
&= \lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2}} \times \lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{2-\dfrac3x}{\sqrt{1+\dfrac7x-\dfrac{2}{x^2}}} \\
&= \lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2}} \times \lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{2-0}{\sqrt{1+0-0}} \\
&= \lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2}} \times 2 \\
&= \lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{2x}{|x|}
\end{align}
it is $2$ as $x\to+\infty$ and $-2$ as $x\to-\infty$.

Comment: It is not a good practice to plug in the limiting values for some expressions in a limit and keeping others unchanged, then simplifying the limit. That way, we can show $\lim_{x\to 0}x\cot(x)=\lim_{x\to 0}0\cdot\cot(x)=0$ which is certainly not true. A better edit to your answer: $$\cdots=\lim_{x\to -\infty}\frac{x(2-3/x)}{\sqrt{x^2(1+7/x-2/x^2)}}=\lim_{y\to 0^-}\frac{1}{\text{sgn}(y)}\cdot\frac{2-3y}{\sqrt{1+7y-2y^2}}=\left(\lim_{y\to 0^-}\frac 1{\text{sgn}(y)}\right)\left(\frac{\displaystyle\lim_{y\to 0^-}2-3y}{\displaystyle\lim_{y\to 0^-}\sqrt{1+7y-2y^2}}\right)=\cdots$$

Answer (score 4):

$$\lim_{x\to -\infty}\left(\frac{2x-3}{\sqrt{x^2+7x-2}}\right) = \lim_{x\to -\infty}\left(\frac{2\frac{x}{|x|}-\frac{3}{|x|}}{\sqrt{1+\frac{7}{x}-\frac{2}{x^2}}}\right)=-2$$

Comment: it is near minus infinity.

Answer (score 3):

$$\lim _{ x\to -\infty  } \frac { 2x-3 }{ \sqrt { x^{ 2 }+7x-2 }  } =\lim _{ x\to -\infty  } \frac { x\left( 2-\frac { 3 }{ x }  \right)  }{ \left| x \right| \sqrt { \left( 1+\frac { 7 }{ x } -\frac { 2 }{ { x }^{ 2 } }  \right)  }  } =\\ =\lim _{ x\to -\infty  } \frac { x\left( 2-\frac { 3 }{ x }  \right)  }{ -x\sqrt { 1+\frac { 7 }{ x } -\frac { 2 }{ { x }^{ 2 } }  }  } =-2\\ $$

Answer (score 1):

**hint**

near $-\infty $,

$$\sqrt {x^2+7x-2}=\sqrt {x^2 (1+\frac {7}{x}-\frac {2}{x^2})} $$

$$=\color {red}{-}x\sqrt {1+\frac {7}{x}-\frac {2}{x^2}} $$